# Problema com Iterator Map C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

o programa para um exercício do URI trava (como em loop infinito) quando a entrada (double) é diferente de um número inteiro ou de um número decimal que não seja alguma coisa com meio (ex: 55.5).
Já tentei modificar o código de diversas maneiras, mas ao que parece o problema está na segunda iteração (it2), pois sem esse trecho do código ele funciona com qualquer decimal. O estranho é que com o código do jeito que está, ele trava exatamente após a leitura do double, no início do código.

O objetivo do exercício é passar o valor informado na entrada para o menor número possível de notas e moedas.

código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

double val=0.0;
map<int,int> nota,moeda;
map<int,int>::reverse_iterator it,it2;

cin >> val;

if(val<0.00 || val>1000000.00)
    return 1;

nota[100]=0;
nota[50]=0;
nota[20]=0;
nota[10]=0;
nota[5]=0;
nota[2]=0;

moeda[100]=0;
moeda[50]=0;
moeda[25]=0;
moeda[10]=0;
moeda[5]=0;
moeda[1]=0;

it=nota.rbegin();

while(val>=2){
    while(val-it->first>=0){
        val-=it->first;
        nota[it->first]++;
    }           
    it++;
}   

it2=moeda.rbegin();

while(val>0){
    while(val-it2->first/100.00>=0){
        val-=it2->first/100.00;
        moeda[it2->first]++;
    }           
    it2++;
}

cout << "NOTAS:" << endl;
for(it=nota.rbegin();it!=nota.rend();it++)
    cout << it->second << " nota(s) de R$ " << fixed << setprecision(2) << it->first/1.0 << endl;
cout << "MOEDAS:" << endl;
for(it2=moeda.rbegin();it2!=moeda.rend();it2++)
    cout << it2->second << " moeda(s) de R$ " << fixed << setprecision(2) << it2->first/100.00 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: O problema resulta do uso do float (ponto flutuante binário) para guardar o montante. Sugiro ler http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html e, ou guardar o montante em duas variáveis separadas pela virgula ou usar uma biblioteca de precisão (por exemplo, GMP).

Comment: Lendo parte do material (pois é muito extenso), concordo que é muito provável o problema ser o tipo da variável. Sendo um problema simples e apenas para exercitar raciocínio lógico, vou tentar implementar utilizando a biblioteca padrão, talvez separando a parte decimal para inteiro. Eu tinha ideia de como era armazenado o float na memória, mas nunca pensei ou tinha visto sobre a precisão. Muito bom  e detalhado o material. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você não implementou uma regra de parada correta, nos dois lops while.
Experimente incluir uma regra que usa os iterator's, pois são estes os mais importantes a serem testados, já que se não estiverem apontando para uma posição válida, uma situação de erro indeterminado pode ocorrer.

Inclua este teste após cada incremento do iterator, para cada caso:

```
if (it == nota.rend()) break;
```

```
if (it2 == moeda.rend()) break;
```

Comment: A condição de parada deveria ser suficiente, nesse caso, por conta da lógica, não fazendo os iterators saírem para uma posição inválida. Assim, a parada no loop por break não completaria toda a tarefa (contar notas e moedas).